Forest branching
I need to change the branches of the following diagram
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
            for tree={
                align=center,
                edge path={
                    \noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}] (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-15pt) -| (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
                },
                if n=2{
                    if ={equal(n_children("!u"),3)}{calign with current}{}}{},
            }
        [The World[Simple Entities[Individuals][Numbers][Properties][Relations]][Complex Entities[Sets][Structures][Facts]]]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}

so that it looks like the one shown in the picture:

However, I do not know what forest options to set.

Er, so how do you want to change them exactly? Also, if you got that code from somewhere, please provide a link. (I'm guessing, but there's no reason anybody would code it that way in current Forest, so unlikely you just read the docs.)

Current forest provides an easier way to set edge path in most cases and provides a library with folder and forked edges. However, switching the direction of growth when using either style - never mind also combining them after the switch - takes a certain amount of brute force. Although forest provides more than enough to make this work, it doesn't handle the situation with any elegance. The result is that small changes to the tree may necessitate radical alterations to the style. That is, the code tends to be one-off and fragile. Still, it isn't hard to make forest do what you want if you don't mind handling some of the layout required manually.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720963/
\forestset{%
  calign/middle edge or midpoint/.style={%
    if={>Ow+P{n children}{isodd(##1)}}{%
      calign'=child edge,
      calign primary child/.process={Ow+x{n children}{\inteval{(##1+1)/2}}},%{##1/2}},
    }{calign'=midpoint},
  },
  declare boolean={switcheroo}{0},
  folders down/.style={%
    delay={%
      where switcheroo={%
        prepend={
          [,
            no edge,
            coordinate,
            calign with current,
            grow'=0,
            delay={%
              while nodewalk valid={n}{append=!n,do dynamics},
            },
            before typesetting nodes={
              calign primary child=1,
              calign=child edge,
              for descendants={%
                folder,
                fork sep'=0pt,
              },
            },
            before computing xy={%
              l'=5pt,
              for descendants={%
                s'-=\baselineskip,
                l'=1.5em,
              }
            }
          ]
        },
      }{},
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}% just here to test the style I replaced the original code with
    % this turns out not to be used in the actual tree, but might be useful elsewhere
  for tree={calign=middle edge or midpoint},
  [1[111[1111111]][2[1][2222222][33333][4]][3[1][2][3][4444][55555]]]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
  % coeden o gwestiwn Frank: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/720894/
  forked edges,% fork the edges
  folders down,% enable a switch to folder style
%   calign=middle edge or midpoint,
  for leaves={% actually say where we want the folder switch to happen
    !u.switcheroo,% in the parents of the terminal nodes
  },
  [The World[Simple Entities[Individuals][Numbers][Properties][Relations]][Complex Entities[Sets][Structures][Facts]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}


